# Mod_rewrite - images, styles and scripts missing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On the start i want you to take notice, i did try finding solution in google, or in stackoverflow. I found some tips, but they didn't work for me, or i simply failed following instructions.

So, here is my site directories:

```
www.domain.pl/index.php    <--index file
www.domain.pl/images/      <--images folder
www.domain.pl/styles/      <--styles folder, for now just 1 css file
www.domain.pl/script/      <--scripts folder, js files, and 1 php file called with include
www.domain.pl/font/        <--font files
```

Now, when i open my website with `www.domain.pl` or `www.domain.pl/index.php` it works like a charm. But i want to be able to add some parameter for example `www.domain.pl/index.php?action=dosmth`, but it doesn't look good for a users, so thats the place where I wanted to use **mod rewrite**.

Now comes tricky part, i want it to look like `www.domain.pl/index/actionparam/` but when i do that, I get error in console, saying my images, scripts, and css cant be loaded/found. (i tried rewriting it like that: `RewriteRule ^index/([^-]+)/script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js$ script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js [L]` but I cant use it for every single image, script, css, or font file. There need to be better way.

**So, my mod rewrite so far:**

```
Options FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.pl/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^index/$ index.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^index/([^-]+)/$ index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

First part, i am trying to add "slash" at the end of url, if user didnt put it there.
`http://domain.pl/index`->`http://domain.pl/index/` or
`http://domain.pl/index/myaction`->`http://domain.pl/index/myaction/`

**Question**
Is it possible to somehow skip folders with images, scripts etc when rewriting it? Or how could i rewrite all images at once?

**Additional question**
`http://domain.pl/myaction/` redirect straight to `http://domain.pl/index.php?action=myaction` right away, without need of putting `/index/` in there? Yes, i am learning mod rewrite.

Comment: you should really use a simple php router script and a simple FallbackResource /index.php in your htaccess , i really wonder how come php webdevs are the only ones that still code like its 1999 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to include `index` in the request, only the parameter. Example:

Request: `http://domain.pl/myaction`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

# Exclude existing files and directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* -  [L]

# Get the parameter and pass it to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?  /index.php?action=$1  [L,NC]
```

Comment: Great answer. Working like a charm, but before i accept it, i would love to learn something. What does `-MultiViews` do in here?

Comment: [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) is a form of search that involves [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html). Basically means the server selects the document "*that best matches the clients capabilities, from one of several available documents*". Since `mod_rewrite` doesn't work as expected with that option enabled, as far as I have seen, it's a good idea to make sure is disabled. As a side note, FollowSymlinks option is mandatory for `mod_rewrite` to work, according to Apache documentation.